# Coordinate as a point in space?

Tags: grammar

Should I use `coordinate` or `coordinates` for a single point in space consisting of multiple numbers that describe a location?

Often I hear *"Give me the coordinates"* when someone requests a single point in space. That would suggest to me that the values belonging to these coordinates are a `coordinate` on there own, yet meaningless on there own. Therefor I assume that in this case the correct way would be *"Give me the coordinate"*. Otherwise the request is about multiple points in space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See, for example, http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coordinate.

The coordinate is "any of a set of numbers" used to define the location of a point.

You therefore need one coordinate per dimension.  To locate a point in two dimensional space, therefore, such as on the surface of the earth, we generally need *two* coordinates *per point,* such as *40° N, 85° W*.

Comment: So I can only say "Give me the coordinate" if I'm talking about a point in 1 dimensional space?

Comment: You could also say it if you knew the latitude but not the longitude of a point, for example.  But without context it sounds a bit weird, since "the coordinates" is so common.